# Why List is allowed but List<Object> is not in following code?

Tags: java, collections, types, covariance, contravariance

I have been playing with generics and variance. I have two lists one without generics and with generics defined like below:

```
List l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Object> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

The compiler works fine for first. But for the second one, it raises the following error:

```
Error:(12, 31) java: incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Object>
```

Now, from my understanding `List` without generics is a `List<Object>` as it allows all types of objects. If both are same, why does compiler have to raise an error?

Can anyone please explain the difference in detail?

**EDIT**
Okay, from the linked duplicate, I was able to learn about Raw Types. But

from

> Just what is the difference between the raw type List and the
>   parameterized type List? Loosely speaking, the former has
>   opted out generic type checking, while the latter explicitly told the
>   compiler that it is capable of holding objects of any type. While you
>   can pass a List to a parameter of type List, you can't pass it
>   to a parameter of type List. There are subtyping rules for
>   generics, and List is a subtype of the raw type List, but not
>   of the parameterized type List. As a consequence, you lose
>   type safety if you use raw type like List, but not if you use a
>   parameterized type like List.

this part :

> As a consequence, you lose type safety if you use raw type like List,
>   but not if you use a parameterized type like List.

Didn't understand above. How is the `List<Object>` more type-safe than `List` if all types extend `java.lang.Object`? Just because of the sub typing rules?

Comment: You would use a `List<?>` instead of a `List<Object>`. You can also use `List<? extends Object>`.

Comment: @MauricePerry Sorry but I found it very confusing.

Comment: I don't blame you

Comment: @MauricePerry Raw Types, Wildcards, how many other things do I need to learn? It seems everything hidden in the case of Raw Types.

Comment: There are more thinks to learn at each new version

Comment: @MauricePerry I edited the question, can you please answer the last part?

Comment: @krupal.agile maybe have a look at [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)